# Psycopg2 - SQL Result to json list

Tags: python, json, psycopg2

Trying to return Psycopg2 results to a Python json list.

```
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT user FROM app.feeders")
        ex1 = self.cursor.fetchall()
        print(ex1)

        json_output = json.dumps(ex1)
        print(json_output)

        result = [r[0] for r in self.cursor.fetchall()]
        print(result)

        return json_output
```

The table app.feeders has a list of users, who I'd like to be represented in a json list ["apple", "banana", "cherry"] however the results for my above attempts are:

```
[('apple',), ('banana',), ('cherry',)]
[["apple"], ["banana"], ["cherry"]]
[]
```

Comment: `[r[0] for r...]` should work.  Have you tried it without doing anything else to the resultset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was passing through the cursor.fetchall() directly. Making the below changes resolved the issue:

From:

```
result = [r[0] for r in self.cursor.fetchall()]
```

To:

```
result = [r[0] for r in ex1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make an [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) directly in Postgres:

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT array_agg(user) FROM app.feeders")
print(cur.fetchone()[0])
```

Out:

```
['tony', 'tom', 'kim']
```